# Finding literal spaces and dashes

Tags: solr, content-search

I'm working with Sitecore 10.1 and SOLR 8.4.0.

I am building a typeahead search that matches items (around 17,000) within a bucket in Sitecore. There are two fields in my template that can be matched, both are single-line text.

Because this is a typeahead suggest, I'm using `StartsWith` in my LINQ query.

```
using (var ctx = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(searchIndex).CreateSearchContext()) {
    var query = ctx.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
        .Where(i => i.TemplateId == SitecoreDefinitions.TypeAheadTemplateId &&
                    (i["display_name"].StartsWith(q) || i["alias"].StartsWith(q)));
    // handle results
}
```

The code above works great until there is a dash or a space in the query, at which point it doesn't treat them literally.

For example, if I look up `Throat Can` my expectation is that it will find "Throat Cancer" as a result. This is the SOLR query I see in the Search log:

```
?q=(_template:("b6c8c774b3064276834161457128d4d1") AND (display_name_t:(throat* can*) OR alias_t:(throat* can*))) AND _val_:__boost&start=0&rows=1000000&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)&wt=xml
```

If I look up "17-H" i get this

```
?q=(_template:("b6c8c774b3064276834161457128d4d1") AND (display_name_t:(17* H*) OR alias_t:(17* H*))) AND _val_:__boost&start=0&rows=1000000&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)&wt=xml
```

If I plug that directly into SOLR and change the display_name_t and alias_t to look for `("throat can*")` or `("17-H")` it returns what I would expect.

I'm hoping there is a way to adjust the translation of the LINQ `StartsWith` query to not tokenize based on dashes or spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `indexType` as `UNTOKENIZED` which means "Phrases will be stored as a whole – the entire value of the field, essentially" so it will consider `17-H` as a single word instead of break into different words. You can do like below:

```
<field fieldName="displayname" storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" />
```